# Error message when closing connection in PostgreSQL

Tags: .net, vb.net, postgresql

I am querying an external database, and it throws an error of:

```
ERROR: 25006: cannot execute UNLISTEN during recovery
```

My understanding is that postgreSQL calls this whenever it is finished, which indicates that this is caused by closing the connection.

The odd thing to me is that it seems the code could open the connection to the database, but then errored when trying to close the connection. Also, this only seems to happen sporadically, so could this be due to the database itself restarting?

How is it postgreSQL could open a connection, but not close one?

Below is the code that is executed, the troublesome line being dbConn.Close()

```
        Dim sConnectionString as String = "Server=10.2.21.46;Port=5432;User Id=myuser;Password=mypsw;Database=demos;"
        Dim sErrorMessage As String = ""
        Dim bConnectionOpen As Boolean = False
        Dim dbConn As Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection = New Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(sConnectionString)
        Try
            dbConn.Open()
            bConnectionOpen = True
        Catch
            sErrorMessage = "open connection fail."
        End Try

        If bConnectionOpen Then
            Dim cmdTxt As String = sQueryString
            Dim cmdTmp As Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(cmdTxt, dbConn)

            Dim bReaderOpen As Boolean = False
            Dim rsTmp As Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader
            Try
                rsTmp = cmdTmp.ExecuteReader()
                bReaderOpen = True
            Catch
                sErrorMessage = "ExecuteReader fail."
            End Try

            If bReaderOpen Then rsTmp.Close()
            rsTmp = Nothing
            dbConn.Close()
        End If
```

Comment: can you paste also the connection string? It can helps..

Comment: Server=10.2.21.46;Port=5432;User Id=user;Password=abc123;Database=demos;

Comment: do you have any triggers defined in database? what I am looking for is whether anything is executing LISTEN or NOTIFY

Comment: You can remove the connection string since is the simplest and contains the psw

Comment: i don't have access to the external database, so i'm not sure. the trigger would have to be executed on connection close though for that to be the cause?

Comment: @trippino i changed the details so the psw and other details are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to PostgreSQL source code [here](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/utility_8c_source.html), this error can only happen if server is trying to perform recovery from bad state or long failed transaction (in other words, it is not feeling very good at the moment).

Confusingly, it is using error code 25006 `ERRCODE_READ_ONLY_SQL_TRANSACTION` in this case. I think what is really happening server does not want to write anything to disk to not disturb current recovery - that's why it is read-only transaction.

I think you should contact admin of that external server and ask him to take a look. It is possible that simple server restart may help. Or, it may need restoring from backup...

**EDIT:**

It is also possible that this server was/is hot-standby server. On hot-standby you will see exact same behavior even for read-only connections. Snippet from [source code](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/utility_8c_source.html):

```
/* 
 * ... there are a few commands that are allowed
 * in "read-only" xacts but cannot be allowed in Hot Standby mode.
 * Those commands should call this function.
 */

PreventCommandDuringRecovery(const char *cmdname)
...
```

Comment: the errors are no longer showing, which would indicate that it is back and working now i guess. so you are saying closing a connection isn't a read only transaction?

Comment: It is also possible that they use(d) some type of hot-standby setup. On hot-standby server you will see exact same behavior even for read-only transactions